# Firestore onSnapshot() method fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I have a vue-cli-4 app with multiple routes and vuex. Firestore database has been connected successfully - my app immediately reflects modifications applied to DB from Firestore console.

Strange behavior begins to happen after leaving the route which contains component "synced" with Firestore and then returning back. In this case **onSnapshot()** method fires multiple times after modifying data in Firestore console.

I wonder whether I should somehow "manually" unsubscribe my component from Firestore each time after leaving the route - maybe on **destroyed()** hook.

Code part: I'm syncing *PieChart.vue* component (located on /pie route) with Firestore by firing **getDataPie** action on **created()** hook.

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'PieChart',

 created () {
   this.getDataPie()
 },

 methods: {
   ...mapActions([
       ...
       'getDataPie',
       ...
    ])
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  ...
</template>
```

in vuex module:

```
import { getDataPie } from '../../helpers/helpersPie.js'

...

actions: {
  ...
  getDataPie: async ({ commit, getters }) => {
    await getDataPie()
  },
  ...
}
```

**getDataPie** function, containing *console.log* which allows me to see how many times 
**onSnapshot()** has been executed:

```
export function getDataPie () {
  // get data from firestore, onSnapshot - changes listener
  let fdata = []
  return db.collection('expenses').onSnapshot(res => {
    console.log('-------on snapshot--------------')
    res.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    const doc = { ...change.doc.data(), id: change.doc.id }

    // forming data array
    switch (change.type) {
      case 'added':
        fdata.push(doc)
        break
      case 'modified':
        const i = fdata.findIndex(i => i.id === doc.id)
        fdata[i] = doc
        break
      case 'removed':
        fdata = fdata.filter(i => i.id !== doc.id)
        break
      default:
        break
      }
    })

    store.commit('SET_RECIEVED_DATA_PIE', fdata)
    !store.getters.initPie && store.commit('SET_INIT_PIE')
  })
}
```

It looks like **onSnapshot()** fires as many times as route **/pie** was entered

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the moment you call `onSnapshot`, Firebase will be listening for snapshot changes until you tell it to stop. Since your code never tells it to stop, the listener continues, even when you navigate away. Then when you navigate back to `/Pie`, you attach a second listener. So at that point your `onSnapshot` listener will be executed twice.

There are two solutions:

1. Detect that you've already attached a listener, and don't attach it when you revisit the same route.
2. Unregister the listener when you navigate away from `/Pie`. You do this by calling the function that is returns from `onSnapshot`:

   ```
   var unsubscribe = db.collection('expenses').onSnapshot(...);
   ```

   And then later:

   ```
   unsubscribe();
   ```

   Also see the Firebase documentation on [detaching listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).

Comment: Solution 2 here is usually preferred. The only time solution 1 would be better is if you intend users to navigate away from a route and then come back right after, as this solution would then prevent you from having to unsubscribe and resubscribe unnecessarily.